# A simpler method or more descriptive answer to the Fourier Transform

Tags: signal, fourier

I'm trying to do a CT Fourier Transform of these two signals
$$e^{-a(t-1)} \cdot u(t-1)$$
and
$$e^{-a(t-1)} \cdot u(t)$$
Where \$a\$ is any real number, and \$u(t)\$ is the unit step function.

[image]

My question is if there is either a property that eliminates the need to evaluate the integral or if there is some simplification of the transform so it's not such a jumble.

I see that i made a mistake with integrating the unit step, and my answer should not have that extra $$t \cdot u(t-1)$$ and $$t \cdot u(t)$$
After the help i got on the DSP exchange and here i ended up with
$$ x_1(F)=\frac{e^{2a+j2\pi\cdot F}}{a+j2\pi\cdot F}$$
and 
$$x_2(F) =\frac{e^a}{a+j2\pi\cdot F} $$
That does seem more elegant than what i previously had, i feel like i could possibly manipulate $x_1(F)$ into a sinc function, but i don't think it's necessary.

Comment: What is \$e^(\$? Also, please rotate your image.

Comment: http://chattypics.com/files/droidUpload_qdg2kdu2di_yp4yyclp6d.jpg That is supposed to be e to the quantity -a(t-1),

Comment: Okay.. I edited it in for you this time. _What exactly is your question?_

Comment: Thanks for fixing that up for me, i don't really get why that didn't work, but my question is if there is either a property that eliminates the need to evaluate the integral or if there is some simplification of the transform so it's not such a jumble.

Comment: I edited the question in. You can edit your questions yourself as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a definite integral with endpoints.  Think about how the properties of \$  u(t) \$ let you reduce the integration boundaries.

Comment: I see that you can instead integrate from 1 to infinity on the first integral, and 0 to infinity on the second, but i don't see what that would change in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should be able to find the transform for the time domain signal \$f(t) = e^{-at}u(t)\$ in your Fourier transform tables.

For your first signal, a table of Fourier transforms like [this one](http://www.ibk.ethz.ch/ch/education/identmeth/fourier.pdf) will tell you that if the transform of \$f(t)\$ is \$F(\omega)\$, then the transform of \$f(t-t_0)\$ is \$F(\omega)e^{-j\omega{}t_0}\$.

For your second signal, realize that you can write \$e^{-a(t-1)}\$ as \$e^{a}e^{-at}\$, meaning this signal is just a constant multiplied by the basic decaying exponential signal.